# How to aggregate list of dates and generate date range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, date-range

I have a list of date which I want to aggregate and generate a date range.

I have attached the result set I have and the result I want to.

Help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot you can refer to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZJYh.png)

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: thanks @HABO I will try to improve in my next question.

Comment: Have a go at searching for `[tsql] combine date ranges` and pick a suitable answer. You'll probably have to fudge things a little since your end _dates_ aren't dates, but leave a strategic dead second between dates every night.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this can be complicated.  This article has it right.  Once you have a table that defines your buckets, consider if the bucket spans the front of a date range is in the middel or overlaps the end of the date range.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/